# Set border-style:none; on my anchor tags but border shows up when I click on a link - why?

Tags: html, css, onclick, border

As you can see from the example below, I have a black background and red links to emphasize this problem of dotted borders showing up on my links when they are clicked. I added `border-style:none` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there some other way to remove the dotted border appearing around the links when they are clicked?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body 
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, serif, sans-serif;
    background:black;
}

#linksouter
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align:left;
}
#linksinner
{
    margin: 80px 0 0 .5em;
    width:100%;
    display:inline;
    height:100%;
}
#linksinner a
{
    color:red;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-style:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="linksouter">
    <div id="linksinner">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the border you see is called an outline. you can get rid of it by putting this style into your `a` rules:

```
outline:none;
```

personally i always define it as a blanket `a` rule near the top of my stylesheets (i really dislike outlines even though i know they have a use)

```
a { outline:none; }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Awesome. Is there anything you don't know?

Comment: The outline is an important part of accessibility. It allows users who cannot use a mouse to tab around the page and see what link has focus.

Comment: Good point Emily. Didn't realize it was needed for accessibility. However, the site I'm designing is intended to be 'design-y' - not maximally accessible.

Comment: Thats correct Emily, it is an important part of accessibility. Unfortunately I'm in a part of the media industry that mostly don't give a rat's ass even if individual developers do.

Answer (score 3):

That´s not the border, it is the outline.

You can disable it by setting:

```
a {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to define all the rules for your link such as Link, Hover, Active, and Visited.

More information: http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm

Comment: Don't forget "focus": link, visited, hover, focus, active is generally accepted as the optimal order. "Focus" is important for accessibility (particularly if the default outline has been disabled) as styling an element when it has focus helps those who cannot use a mouse to see when they can perform the equivalent action to clicking. Generally, a good idea is to make "hover" and "focus" have the same styles.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using those pseudo selectors on links?
like

```
a:hover
a:active
```

Coz when you set the css in just using a, it will only change the static appearance on the link.